# Yii authenticate, using this when is not in object context

Tags: php, yii, authentication

I'm getting this error in login after I change server.

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

in accountController.php:

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Account'];
if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) {
    ...
}
```

in account.php

```
public $email;
public $password;
private $_identity;
.....
public static function authenticate()
{
    $this->_identity = new UserIdentity(
        $this->email,
        $this->password
    );
}
```

_indentity, email and password are not in object context, how that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `$this` in  static method. Static methods do not run on an object, they are simply a function namespaced to a class.

Perhaps your function should not be marked as static?

Or possibly your `$_identity` should be static. In that case you will be able to access it via `myClass::$_identity`

Comment: thanks, was for that. now is working, but is strange because worked in the other server.